# GIT how move main branch to another branch and clean the main branch?

Tags: git, github

by mistake I pushed to main branch my code, it was an empty project so main branch didn't have any commit

I need move the pushed commits to the main branch to another branch and keep the main branch as empty or at least with just a new readme file (the initial main branch was totally empty so no readme nor any other file) to make matters worse, the initial commit pushed to the main branch already contains code and not just a readme

My idea was renaming the branches but because main branch didn't have any initial commit I cannot restore to that state, I think that a cherry pick could not work neither for the same reason

is there an easy way to achieve this in a clear way? by the way, there are not other contributors in the project right now so restart the branch hopefully will not cause any trouble... thank guys!

Comment: Branches are just pointers to commits. If you want to change where a remote branch points to, just push the id you want. There are some rules that apply but for your scenario, you will probably need to just force-push (because you are the sole developer and no one has pulled that, right?). `git push -f some-remote some-commit-id:the-remote-branch`

Comment: It's very important to use accurate terminology when you describe something in Git. Did you really _push_ to the main branch, or did you _merge_ to the main branch? Or both?

Comment: And for local branches, just use `git checkout some-branch; git reset --hard the-commit-id-i-want-for-this-branch`. Make sure to _not_ have any pending changes in the working tree because _hard-resetting_ will get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a branch with no commits, you can do

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch
```

This will create branch `new-branch` with no commits. All files in the working directory will become unstaged, but remain unchanged. You can now follow up with

```
git add README.txt
git commit
```

to create the first commit on `new-branch` that has only a readme text.

As next steps, you can now [rename your branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m)

```
git branch -m main old-main
git branch -m new-branch main
```

to make the new branch `main`.

Comment: thank you! orphan option was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can clear wrong pushed data from master branch using below steps -

1. Create a **backup branch from master branch** so if can have backup of pushed code.
2. **Checkout master branch in local and revert the wrong commits and push this master branch from local** again so you master branch will clear and remain only old code.

I hope this might fix your issue.

Thanks